# Accessing matrix as texture in glsl shader

Tags: c++, opengl, matrix, glsl, textures

I have a matrix which has 149 rows and 210 cols. I want to sent it to shader to do some calculation. Values of the matrix are between 9-128. I've used the following for binding it to the texture:

```
m_GLTextureNNZ = new QOpenGLTexture(QOpenGLTexture::Target::Target2DArray);
m_GLTextureNNZ->create();
m_GLTextureNNZ->bind(indx);
m_GLTextureNNZ->setMinificationFilter(QOpenGLTexture::Nearest); 
m_GLTextureNNZ->setMagnificationFilter(QOpenGLTexture::Nearest);
m_GLTextureNNZ->setLayers(1);
m_GLTextureNNZ->setFormat(QOpenGLTexture::R8U);
m_GLTextureNNZ->setSize(m_sizeNZ2DCoeff_r,m_sizeNZ2DCoeff_c,1);
m_GLTextureNNZ->setWrapMode(QOpenGLTexture::ClampToEdge);
m_GLTextureNNZ->allocateStorage(QOpenGLTexture::Red, QOpenGLTexture::UInt8);

m_GLTextureNNZ->setData(0, 0, QOpenGLTexture::Red, QOpenGLTexture::UInt8, m_NNZ.data());
```

and in the shader I want to access a specific row and col of this texture:

```
uniform usampler2DArray NNZ;
vec3 getTexCoord(ivec2 indx, ivec3 tsize )
 {
  // ivec3 size = textureSize()
  return vec3( (indx.x+0.5)/tsize.x , (indx.y+0.5)/tsize.y , tsize.z);
 }
 .
 .
 .
 ivec3 patchedTexSize = textureSize(NNZ,0);
 vec3 texCoord = getTexCoord( ivec2(0,0),  ivec3(patchedTexSize.xy,0));

 uint iNNZ =  texture(NNZ, texCoord).r;
```

So based on my matrix (0,0) should have a value of 1. however I'm not getting this value. Is there something that I'm missing?

EDIT: So I tested with all zeros matrix and the value that I get from texture lookup, no matter what the texcoords are is 2^8-1.

Comment: Why is your 2D matrix addressed in 3D?

Comment: @BDL For testing now I'm only using one matrix but I can have 128 of this matrix as an array.

Comment: your `texcoord.z` seems to be wrong, since `textureSize.z` will be the maximum layer index plus one. Apart from that, I don't understandy why you even go the normalized texcoords route, and not use `texelFetch` directly.

Comment: @derhass I corrected the texcoord.z and replaced it with 0. still I get strange values. I added an edit to my question about how the values look like. I tried texelFetch and it's the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that my data was `int` and I was trying to create an unsigned bit texture. So I converted my data to `uint8_t` and it works. Also, I needed to add `glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);` to be sure the alignment of the pixels are correct.